# ReactiveKit migration from v4.x to v5.x

Tags: ios, swift3, reactivekit, swiftbond

I'm trying to migrate my project to Swift 3.
I am using ReactiveKit and Bond and I am struggling with some conversions.

1) Most of my extensions used to look like this:

```
extension UIView {

public var bnd_superview: Observable<UIView?> {
    return bnd_associatedObservableForValueForKey("superview")
}
```

I can't find what `bnd_associatedObservableForValueForKey` was changed to.

2) I have the following code:

```
self.myButton.bnd_selected.next(false)
```

it should change to:

```
self.myButton.reactive.isSelected.next(false)
```

but I get the following error:

> Value of type 'Bond' has no member 'next'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one can be replaced by `Bond` type. You can also do it as a `ReactiveExtensions` extension instead as a `UIView` extension, so you get `.reactive` prefix.

```
extension ReactiveExtensions where Base: UIView {

    public var superview: Bond<UIView?> {
        return bond { view, superview in
            view.superview = superview
        }
    }
}
```

You can then bind a signal to your bond.

```
let view: SafeSignal<UIView> = ...
view.bind(to: someView.reactive.superview)
```

Bonds cannot be observed though, just like there is no way to observe `UIView.superview`. KVO might work, but UIKit is not KVO compliant.

As for the second question, `isSelected` is of type `Bond` and yes, it does not have the method `next`. It is used to bind signals.

You should just do:

`self.myButton.isSelected = false`

Comment: I have many uses for .next in my app. Most of them are not for Bool's.
Is there any extension I can use to add .next to Bond?

Comment: You could do `SafeSignal.just("abc").bind(to: textField.reactive.text)` and you could pull that into an extension if you really wanted to.